# Simulate static ips in a private netwrok

Tags: ip, network-monitoring

This is the context:
We are trying to monitor via SNMP a set of devices. Unfortunately, all our solutions monitor by IP, and this set of devices change ips regularly (doesn't matter why, think of it as business rules). Once ip is changed, monitoring is lost and it's a problem.

What we seek:
We want to put a layer between the monitoring tool and the devices, the layer receives the query towards a certain static IP and the layer translates it to the current ip of the device assigned to that static IP (kindn of an alias IP).

Is there any tool that does something like that?

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to query on an IP? Most o the internet had a similar problem and it just invented hosts files and later DNS. And DNS with a short timeout probably does what you want it to do.